# Edit html code with lxml without

Tags: python, lxml

Suppose I have html code. It is broken (it is given from another program). I have to find all images in it, and change src attribute to some code. And thats all - it SHOULD stay broken in final.

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

def test(text):
    text = analyze_dir_template_imgs(text)
    return text

def analyze_dir_template_imgs(text):
    ts = [
        {
            'name':'img',
            'path':"//img[@src]",
            'attrib': 'src',
        },
    ]

    parser = etree.HTMLParser()

    for t in ts:
        tree = etree.parse(StringIO(text), parser)
        path = t['path']
        name = t['name']
        attrib = t.get('attrib', False)

        text = str_repr(tree.getroot())

        #text_to_file(text, 'temp/template_dir.html', 0, 'wb')

        links = tree.xpath(path)

        i = 0
        for l in links:
            i+=1
            #print
            #print l
            y0 = l.attrib[attrib]
            print y0

            x0 = str_repr(l)
            if name=='img':
                repl_to = '[image]'

                x0_new = x0.replace(y0, repl_to)

                text = text.replace(x0, x0_new)
    print text
    return text

def str_repr(el, enc='utf-8'):
    text = etree.tostring(el, pretty_print=True, method='xml', encoding=enc)
    return text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = u'''
<a href="[link]">[name]</a>
            </h2>

<img width="280" style= "margin: 10px; float:left;" alt ="привет мир" src = "/[[template]]/image.jpg"><p>[[body]]</p>

<div class="jcomments-links">
<a href="[link]" class="readmore-link">more...</a> </div>



<div class="item-separator">'''

    test(text)
```

But the problem is that during this process lxml corrects the html code. I mean that the result is

```
<html><body>
<a href="%5Blink%5D">[name]</a>
...
```

But my result should start from

```
<a href="[link]">[name]</a>
```

because it was the start of the initial code.

This is bad, because my task is only to change src, and this new changed code will be send to another script which will gather together different pieces of code.

And another problem is that `y0 = l.attrib[attrib]` gives `/[[template]]/image.jpg`, but `x0 = str_repr(l)` gives `<img width="280" style="margin: 10px; float:left;" alt="привет мир" src="/%5B%5Btemplate%5D%5D/image.jpg"><p>[[body]]</p>` - as you see special symbols like `[` are changed to `/%5B` , but I want to get this part as it was in original html code.

How to solve this problem correctly using lxml? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace following line:

```
text = etree.tostring(el, pretty_print=True, method='html', encoding=enc)
```

with:

```
text = etree.tostring(el, pretty_print=True, method='xml', encoding=enc)
```

---

```
>>> root = etree.fromstring('<a href="[link]">more...</a>')
>>> etree.tostring(root, method='html')
'<a href="%5Blink%5D">more...</a>'
>>> etree.tostring(root, method='xml')
'<a href="[link]">more...</a>'
```

Comment: This is much better. But I see another problem - suppose I have cyrillic in my html.

    root = etree.fromstring(u'<a href="[link]" alt="привет мир">more...</a>')
    print etree.tostring(root, method='html')
    print etree.tostring(root, method='xml')

The result in both cases will be like `alt="&#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090; &#1084;&#1080;&#1088;"` - and this is not what I need, because the result is encoded.

Comment: @SKulibin, Which encoding do you use? With `utf-8` encoding, I get the expected output.

Comment: I think this is what I need - ` print etree.tostring(root, method='xml', encoding='utf-8')` solves the problem, thanks.

Comment: I have checked the full code and see the problem. I have changed my full code in the answer, main change is:

    def str_repr(el, enc='utf-8'):
       text = etree.tostring(el, pretty_print=True, method='xml', encoding=enc)
        return text

But the result starts from `<html>
  <body><a href="[link]">[name]</a>`

Comment: @SKulibin, Try `def str_repr(el, enc='utf-8'): return ''.join(child if isinstance(child, basestring) else etree.tostring(child, encoding=enc) for child in el.xpath('body/*'))`

Comment: It try to correct html. It has removed </h2>, and made `<div class="item-separator"/>`

Comment: This func has problems. `x0 = str_repr(l)` from my example give empty string as a result. 

But I have found one more problem - previous variant of str_repr gives `<img width="280" style="margin: 10px; float:left;" alt="&#x43F;&#x440;&#x438;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442; &#x43C;&#x438;&#x440;" src="/[[template]]/image.jpg"/>` as a result of `x0 = str_repr(l)`, so there is problem with coding (but ing `str_repr(tree.getroot())` everything is ok with encoding).